# MAMP server error 500

Tags: server, mamp

While writing simple mysql_connect, I am getting server error.

```
<?php


$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "roo1t";

$databaseName = "alphacrm";

$dbConnected = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

?>
```

I tried to echo the status of $dbConnected with if block, but I think, am getting error due to mysql_connect.

Comment: What have you tried this far? Have you been able to connect to your MySQL database with its associated command line utility, `mysql(1)`, for example? What is the exact error message you get when calling `mysql_connect()`? Are you sure your username, password, and other details are correct?

Comment: Problem solved. I was using "mysql_connect", tried using "mysqli_connect" and established connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change this line:

```
$dbConnected = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
```

to this:

```
$dbConnected = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
```